# stored procedure with creating temporary table in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getpatientclaim(IN idd int)  BEGIN 

create temporary table spec(patient_id int,claim_id int,procedure_code int);

insert INTO spec SELECT p.patient_id,p.claim_id,p.procedure_code FROM 
payment p LEFT JOIN patient_visit_cpt pvc ON p.patient_id = pvc.patient_id
WHERE p.claim_id = idd; 
END
```

it successfully created and i tried to call procedure like this

```
call getpatientclaim(4963);
```

output comes like :

> it returned an empty result set.

The select query returns many rows but in procedure it returns empty. please help

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
SELECT * FROM `spec`;
```

at the end of your procedure body (before `END`).

But do you really need a temporary table for this? Just

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getpatientclaim(IN idd int)  BEGIN 
     SELECT p.patient_id,p.claim_id,p.procedure_code 
     FROM payment p LEFT JOIN patient_visit_cpt pvc ON p.patient_id = pvc.patient_id
     WHERE p.claim_id = idd; 
END
```

would produce the same outcome. (And in that case a `VIEW` would probably more appropriate.)